# PHP/MySQL Shopping Cart- Add Quantity Questions

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I am working on a shopping cart using PHP and MySQL. My current task is writing code for adding an item to a shopping cart, the site detects the item is already in the shopping cart. It should then increment the quantity instead of added a separate item.

My while loop to display the shopping cart table via the browser looks like the following:

```
<tr>
<td> $item_title <br></td>
<td> \$ $item_price <br> </td>
<td> $item_qty </td>
<td> $total_price </td>
<td> <a href = "removefromcart.php?id=$id">remove</a>
</td>
`enter code here`</tr>
```

Comment: We might be able to help if you we can see your code for adding a new product.  Likely you need to have a field in your cart table that houses quantity.  If a duplicate product is added, increase the quantity and factor that into your sub total functions.

Comment: OK- thank you for the quick response.  How can I show more of the code? I was told by stack overflow I needed a higher reputation to display certain PHP tags.  The problem is I am a new user.

Comment: Is this written in a PHP framework?  How are you handling the cart objects now.  Is it driven by a database or is purely session based?

Comment: It is purely session based.